# how to split the formdata in serverless

Tags: node.js, serverless

im getting the form data in event.body as follows

{ profileImage: '------WebKitFormBoundarySt2NUqsKdknDPfBB\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="profileImage"\r\n\r\ndata:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEhUTEhIWFRUVFRYWFhUWFxUXFxUVFRUWFhUVFRcYHSggGBolHRUXITEhJSktLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGy0fHyUtMS0tLS0vLS0tLS0tNystLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAIcBdgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAIDBQYBB//EAEMQAAIBAgQEAwYCCAMIAgMAAAECEQADBBIhMQUTIkEGMlEjYXGBkaEUsTNCUnLB0eHwJHOzBxU0Q1NigrKS8SWD0v/EABkBAAMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwAEBf/EAC0RAAICAAQFAwQCAwEAAAAAAAABAhEDEiExIjJBcYETI2EzQpHwUdEEwfGx/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDNWkqUW67bSplWvYOKyNbdcuWZopRTslFAZVNhz6VwWqsrluouVV4sjLQFFupOTRC26nS3RFsBFmnCzVgtinjD0LNTK8WakWzRxw5FdFitZqYOgjtT4NFLh6lFikdDaglu3RCWZohEjtUwiKRsdAq2IqQ2akze6umaWmbMgRlYU5ffRZtyKjSySdBR0rUDbvQgdB6TUXJnYVaLge7GB/feiLaAeVY95/uTUJf5MY7alY4E5b6FI2FIMER8feAR9iPrTuRW14xheZZw6wM3KzA7TlVJGvu/IVRfhYJB3BI+YMU2HjqcbExMLI6KprdN5NWhsRTORVUyTK9bNELYmiVsVIFrNmTADbrgtUebNdFqtYAEWalXD0WLVOCVrMmDtYqBrNWfL0pow9BOjS1K3k0uRVsMOKRsCjnFysqeRXPw9WvIrvIrZgUVP4ekcPVt+HrhsVswaZTnD1G2Hq7OHpjYatmNlKJsNUD4er9sNUD4ahmDRQvYod7FX1zDULdsUjY6RRvYpVYvYpVMoCKBTqjC09Qa6lEDkSKacWri26lW1T0hHJkUU4JRK2qeLVGxGCrbqW3bolbVSLbrWASqumlEKoio1tVIqVNodTO5Z7U4WBT0WiLaUj0HTsHFn3U8WfdRq26eLdJmGADh6YbJqzFukbNZSA0VvKpcqjmsGm8qmTEYIqVPZXUxp/fapRarvLPYx/fapY74GUwOdDSANT9T/enyppcnYfM6fbenFQNT9T/X8qaWJ2HzOn23rzj0jS4ieVYLExyQoAWetsoVp7CCQfiD2qqx2CZDmJHUzGB21n+NXbfoLEsY5dsQBpJKQ3w7H4+6ucQw/MKqCJObL7zGgn3xVcGajuQxo5lpuZ42waiNqjVtGupZDJnUgjMUMdiADv30P2rutI4WrQCLNSW8LJjvDH/4qWP2BqDE4ki5ylJBy5tAJ7aazvO+lXfh5FzWgfMeaDJliPaQCSSTpXPiY0lr0s6MPBg9OtWVQtU4Wqs7+AyAGQRJGnb+4P0qEWq6VNPVHK4tOmBi1XeVRotV0Wq1goDFunC3RgtV0WqGYNAnLpcqjxaApG3QzBygAtU4WqN5VOWzWzmUQEWacLFHhK7kpM5RQADYqNrFWJWmFK2Y2UrHsUO9irdkqJrNHMDKUz2KGu4art7FDXrNByGUTP3rIFcqxvYelQtBMyqipFt11Eoi3brrRBsYtqp0tVLbtUQlqjZgdbVSCzRaW/UVILM0MwKBFsU8WqLFsinC3QzGoHSxUy2KmVKmQUrbCqIBh6lS1RKJNSBRSORRIGFuuhTRi2xTslLmDQKi08rRHKFcyULCDZad+HooWadya2YFAf4aoMTaIjWP799WTLl1Jj40DjbgaACdNyB/Op4s+FophQ40wIqF1P1O/wAJP5U0sew+Z0/r9qkYKuug953Puk6mmFidh9dP6/auI7jT3WixYzEwUtrA2kskNr9Pmd9KqL17lsyZ8zJcLIQIyhgtxrZkk6FwfgyfAWmIaLOHzZiClsQugkvbh/l6TsT7qpeJ4ZObfuK5LZrassQEYWlI9+qke7U9xoJcjF6mbx/im9eZnRciyGYWwWhZliWI9AdRFXnBONLbsuAucZg6mBoWUCfpH3rz/hmPum1dCJKlOqTAUEESRuTrVpYuXWtqEPLEAGepmgAAjTTvt9arBt76k5JK6pFs2JN3EM7EiUJMNl0GUCTpHbvWr8MOk2gpE+12M/8AUIk/SsPwvDS4V5fpYy57yN9ffW68NFQbKrGnO8olR+kIgjQ/zoz5PIIXn8D8OGm/M5Dc6ZmJVnzQO25n1qQW6XD1zXLzaasukjMIzBSw3AOsVYC3VoSpEJxuTARarvKo7JXCtPmEyAfKpwSistRXbqL5mA+ev0oZgqBFlpwShb3Fra7Sft+ev2qbh2K5oJiIMd/T30vqJukP6bWrJctdy1JSNGwURZKaVqY1GawSJqYRUxFNIo2LRGRTGFTFaaVrWagVxQt0Ue6VBct1rBTKq6tKirlqlWDTMhbSirduu2rVF27NdWY56FaSiFSnW7VTpaoWHUjVfdUvL9wp626mRawCAW6cLVFkT2p4t0uYOUECU8W6K5dDWsUHuizbUs8TJDKiztmeO86QDNBzSGWG3sOFuni3UhbKyq4yszZYkMN4kEbjv/AU7i1h7aSDHUBm1IjWdiIpPVjddRvSktWcWngUB4ltM2Fw+V8s27rORMsEywDHx71BguO4q2q28Zh1e04Y4fEWQVNvfKl9GM6/tKSPdUfXW9FvR6WXCilkqfAILltWGhgTqCGnYgjaum2RoRTwxIy2JyhJbjESpFWuqlOC0WZFP4mulLaRoWuBZ00lWM9WnaqvD30cgK8kJ1wZ1zvu3wy7UX45Hsbek+2XSJnoftVBwGTduyCui6SJ2EbbVHEXDZ0YT18F0wVfQT9T/E0wsew+un9ftTjlX0E/U/xNNLHsPrp/X7VznQaPEXItYfMCRkQQJy6vbh/iJ2+PuNZi49q6+IvITmN0WriE+VrUorAdwQpIP7w9Z02JMWsPmUkZLYIk5dXtw3xH8/Way2IwVtGuXEObm3bmZhOkO0qROhBmffrsRQfIxPuXc864WH5T5WUCBmnUneAJq6s2WuW1JfIoXUISqkECMzEn3+7WqPAW5tPLsIA0GgY67mrG8Ey2zefXLKjKZgwNFUARp+0KeAst2W/CVtKRJUoFfUnMJzDbeflW68NYpWNpVkxzdYgahysT8RWI8PYu2kHaVMDJLHrGuUHT4z33rS+HOL2/xdq2VcM2YdQAibbZZ17/AMaaT4PIsV7ngvuC/pL8nUMARB0AzAGdjt29atstVXBNbuI3zZ9doiWiO/pPxq5C0yYjWrIytcy1NlrmWjYKKnxBe5eHuP6Bdve6j+NZV8RqBnEk+WQDEfCTWk8a6YK7/wDr/wBVKylsIAuS2y6+bLlG22sGto0+w6tV3DgfQfaPzq78PglW/e/hVGJ9w+9FW+N28LabO3W5ItLlJDMFGmg0Esu571KDplZq0aYiorrhRLEAe+s14U8S3Llm4+LhXF0hVC5YTIhAC7nUtVX4g8StcuIqCFUMRO5aAJPwE6e+rZtLJZNaNdd4kg9T8oH3oldQD6gH61kHuKVBGYtI1IYAbSJbT6VrsMZRD6qp+oFHVPUVpVodK1winmuU1i0RkVyKfSisaiFhULiiWWo3FYFAFwUqmuLSrBozFlaNsgVDZt0dZt10HPqOtgelToDTrQWQsiTsO5ogIsxIDb5e8fDftS547DZZbkMe6nolTZKcEo2LQ1bdPRZMDUxMDeBuYp6pTeEuPxm2yET/AOIJ+evx0qWJLKrK4cczoDx2MNtXYKSLaZ2IEnWYCjuZA+tG2b2ZbbTqXt7af8wCKquKcRW+l+4rZGNsKEOQglSeo9yNj28p99WuGnl25/6lvXX/AKojtSW2WSpGdwZH4q4VvNd9uJDMWFnqMW10gRqIHprQt7xC16/fsOuZEclAFJYG22QgxoV1J6v6UeM34hsyhPbaZWzczq850G4gxvrrWT4OznH4oKV812Zk6c8bBSJNQWuIij+mzTcc4jh7uGw66sVS8MgDSH6MpIG40J9NKrcCi5WOGxPMALHE4Z8zBH73bYeHtxOrCV2Bquct0RExcmZiJExRfEHV7ac7Dm2yg8nEJ7RXWD0ORDW2M95HuG9RUuBsL5kje+HLg5KkGRlX09+krppVlcgj4fUfD+VZHAYl0S2YynlrJGUht4JjQ+mvpVzhuJhtGhT69v79xqDxUsStmWWG/TvcOC/37jtXQtdwuqiSW7SY7GI2G23rprNTZa9PMcFGZ8ZqeXZy5Z56xmkLOR941is7wywRib6swYgJJUFBqqnQTPf11rT+NVHKsyxUfiElgQpAyPJDHRfjWS8P5GxOJCPnUcuDnLk9C5padeqaSb0K4a1Lw5V00HuG5+Q3qMsewPz0H8/tUl27bt6FlX3SB9qr7/GLY8uZvgIH31+1c7kludKTZsb5izYJWZS2pEnL1Pb6h6sO3z9azGMVAHNogqcRdz6AMLmYhlYeogfEZT3rT4PEh8PYYLrltqQToAxTUdifT+uua4gE6ikj292VYQ2fMc0+o2IPoRsQaDdwtE5KpK/5PLMIEyNm1MDLqd9dgN+1XlnFLbRBka5cKyCoViNds+pHwiqbDOAjAKSYGyzA1nXt2+lW1jiLJaVLSZ5GpBYAERuInvuDVYCyW4R4dxjri7jNbuZjajIozMOq3EzAGg3NWVi6xxqMVKGNmIzCLbQdNB2NV3hLF3ExjlrZd2tEZUy6dVszNzYQN6ucUH/HoXQISgOUNngBHUSY36ZoYj9t9wQXueDceHmHMvzvmktO8lu3aJHfXWr8wNToPU1hOL2A9q8vpdRtMuZvcS5Cjz/Re5NB4jEszHO5b4kn19Zpm6NGNtnoTX0H6w+Wv5VX8V47bsWnuFSwtozkAgEhRJArz69xt1xVgfjFdZcPYHJ6iLZ6RllhlMHU/wAAR/FOOa5aukgD2bCB6RMe+nUdDUibi3jq7i0NpcLy7TkS5LsenrWGhVElR61aA3Sq5wgX3SxmPXSspiXu5V5l23GkW1Uyej1Zu3uFa7h1pSEL3SxNvNlLAAdIPlWJpnHKmvgVO2u44j1P8KG8QEfgbhC5iLiwdDlOU9cnaPXeijHYfb+NAeJ8SBg2QkqWYsD0wQigFdToTnG2uhqENy8tjJ+HmIsRbt8wFycxDpJyW+oh5YzvPep7z3OYucKOloCzptvQPCdLUXLnIOYkqoa2T0W9AHOcxqJ706zyzd6GZuhpLZpO37VVk+EklxG59pkUtkC9OgDE9oObT8q1uCHs0/cX/wBRWMbEWVtqebJAWesso2mQDAracPINq2RsbaEH1BURTN8XgRLh8kkUop0Uoo2ChkVyKkilFaw0REVGy0SRUbLWs1AVxaVTOtcoWCihsLRmyk+gP5VHYt0U6dDfun8jVrI0zOeHbpa5bZtST/OrriyEuzC2Hy8odLEOoZiGLgZxAGuqr36vSh8M+a3+8dvnV1xpQS5a20BsPD7CeYY8wjTvBBg/XkfO/wB6nWuVFtxbHWlUtbaGBgi70KCWAHU0CCdAQdzvXMNjbb3VQGAWKkmPgI+JrMY7HKwv21uuWBb2WIBynI/UVugghYByguBrsdqG8PGLw6SJvqdTM9Y6hpRniSjsxIRUt0brEPbVLjJdS5kDaKwkuttrnLET1Qu3pWLueIXS+WSFbLmKFSRqgDSSZ3gaRtUPhW6SjrqRzMSY9D+DgdtoYj4mheIXCbzw6FerQRMwddvL/wD1S4k5OA0IpS0J/DmOa9gMQ5trBWGAbVoI0UEd9tT3rbYUezt6Hz2/X/qivNvDF5E4dOZ1J5uYjmFRq0ECMpMAH/x7VrLfHHLLZCqmWGLE55y+0AgQBMAd96b1FHV/BlFu6+Rtor+IuZLjP7bqDFjyur9GMw2BkaelYzgrr/vO/nnKXvSBm6jzxCkLqw302q7scSvPfm6VXNeXILZ8w5i9TzqJHaqrgTMvFsRkiS18amAAbyzOmvbT70kJKU1Q8lUGFcWCc1hqq8y9lWGXTOcqlYkfCO1F3xdNhmTEribQkXLbEXWwz6wVdDmtgH9Vun41Y+JOCXLTi6GV+Y2IYjy5Yfq3mRr8azmOfDuYNi5YxCghbpWUvqRBHNtbEiOl1/8ALtUknkaM3xIvsDjrZS2q3QxyDpJXMsFpXT3/AD1qHjWOe0qNbjNzrYymIaW1UyDAO01iONW7isk28jKoGZQBn1MOcveNJ91Rjjly4EtXWLILltswnOAG1grrMExGvpUMTA9zMdEMT26PeeDXM9i2xAUldVEQh7poSOk9Oh7Udlqt8Ka4SyRBBWQwIOdSTldoAGZhBbTzEzrVsFrvs4aPP/8AaTeC3cKCCw5gJQDNmEPIy9+2nvrFYW+Ti8QQGTMLUr5Yi2oAIBPpPzrUf7TMUTi7FtYlCu5IDFgxBMagCY+dZTD2iMVfzlWJW2TlnL5QNJJOwpMX6TfyVwudL4D8w/8Ar+lNLegP5f1rpuD1+mv5U0v7j+Veedp6LwRiuHssBJy2lO5GViub5x37fnT8YI515FVlFu4p1llY3bYdmBOqtLGV2OhEGZs+FOy4aywGuW0pO4ysUkfSde0VTXeI3LvNW5bgreZUuCAHRHYAMDrmEASNCN9tejD+j+TnxPqfg8ywlxuWwCyDlkyBHmj496vMG93IospIgSXgAbRoD3179qocGG5bQVA0kHc+aI+/1q/wyXCqi2y2+kTOs6CNwff2rpgRn1CODYTEJii7KGY2mEZ8uhKGZ12jaa0+F4Tcu30uMwzhHhFkjp5pgsxknU9vSqXglp0uAApcbI+pJC6kE7DWNorZeHw/OtFsu13RBA2uSNf6UZrg8ghz+AbiF2EuglgC65cgObNoWAKDMZJO20dtaxuM4qxJCdI9e+529K0/iS6VtXCxITnJDaQpWQYzGAfN8z3rza5xK3JiT8v50JVSGjuy7vG5zMMSqlQDqDcLIMjRsoWfWdNdJOtc443sbhg+VhOseU+tBXGRruGIssCsjmRoWNsmT7TuP+07du8/HH9hc6v1W6e3l3+Paq3owIXJCoCuE5Y0m43LDHo7BSWM+/1racFZAqZLZ/R6kLlBMCdTE/GsJdxNrICMTcutp0grkHRB8ihdPee1bH8besWkYokBVQAFiTK7zAj4UZtU+37sJFO13D2J9PvVR4rH+HB5Wczc6oX2fSmskz9PSh34xcP7I+A/nNQcVvl8KS97KQ1yB7MZ+hOkTr/8dda5MLETlR0YkGo2Z/w+pW1Fqyr9ROZ1ZP1LUNl6mbMNZkU3ja3YBuBBoYCBhG3rS4UgW1F26cP1ElED280pbnpks0GRNC8RFnXlFmMGWbPqJH7VXk+EklxGxxLucBaHLAXlWeosJbpXXKAd/ea9E4N/w9j/ACbX+mted4m0wwFom6xBs2YtwgABVYG2Yx8a9F4KP8PY/wAm1/prTSfF4FiuHyFUqdXK1mo5FKKcBSihYaGkUxhUsUxhWs1AzilTrgpULNRWWBRNxehv3W/I0ywlE3U6G/db8jVsxGjI8HsKly0FbMCEaR2LoHZe+xYj5UVxTKt26+W4hY4UcxSIfrYBRqkATB6zvt2ID41kvWR0yLWH9dvw6R9qJfEhnunPcRicLOU9BGdgBo4MGIaR6b7Dkzp4rX7udOVqCZXXcdmN8fic49p7G8mUiSQFF0+UAsFADiZGnameHhF4dJWb6nXv1jUaV265ZcQOZYu9XlgWmHtB5m6Cx7bnU99iNwfodjlI9rm12OsyNBpWxNmLhldh8ayoyqG/Sucw081tUKe/Y/X62uA4TdvTy7IB5ZhswBMKZWNBPfX0rMYTyTB3Ovz8o03r0PwEANAGHTe0bcnLuPd2+VUa4KNHmM1wWzdThyKSqkPcgMDoZfVmzZY+Wxo7D5Tf0BujsW1MhPN1R5Tr8tKlwdtWwWIzWswAE3IXQAjRTJad9h3rQYTgSZlutcYsxRSBAWGIQjWTMe+p4mG5aL4GhJK/Jk+Blec/KJHtlF3OTvzk6LYI0AMaDtQ/DMg4li2uPy4N6CHCEk3l6Qd9vTXStOMEqXwHAIW4BaIzajODLTpMRtsaznh+4w4liyq5zN7TMoj266kmf561sOLjJWGcrgzXeI3DYXDF7jKSl8khoLEldCTqZ+9Zu9YxSpmfl3bB2blhLlonZBcswrgHs4JrS8bJ/C4WEznl39JAjy9Un0rGpawodjb5li+whgbdy0t8R1Q1stbuzv1kHWt0Ee//AAosTiWd2zdjA0AMa+m/xoT8Mruo8pZlAb0JIE6b0+9531nq32qC9sfhTsZbHvvgqyVwVlSjIVDghs+pFxgXGcA5WPUO0MI0irwLWe/2dMp4bhsrlxkIltCCHYFdzoplR7gNtqB8d8WvWbuGt2nKrcPVAGozoI+jGtu6Eoynj3q4mULFQq2mDLEghQJk6frVRZLYu3CGz+UZmcOTCjdpPen8axGbHnmAv7NAQUkt5YGUb6fWrDw7iUN+9C5MoSFZQkaD9XtO/wA6OJH22vkMHxp/AKll28qMfeFJH12qZOF3j+rHxI/hJrStiB6z8AT+VQtdP7J+w/M1yrBR0PEZdYXD3LeHskbhLalhqCpa3mXX1AP0qmxt3OCSgtkX7qkSYbKxAdZ1Uncj5jfTQXRc5WHZREW1DHQ9Je1K/AgH6VncZiWcNzECML91enZ1VmCMy6gEgE767wDIp0qw6XySk7mmeW4FCbbkM0CJA777/b61epbYopNxlAUeSFBEDQsWUaR696z2ERCjZiMwjLJM95AHft9KvrVqwUQ4gksF0kmY3gAaxrVYCy6llwAFrmS0w6UY5rkPuy5vKYmT6mtNwHGXUxdpGuZwAx0VADntuxAgaak1lvDlsNfYYe4bK8swQoYxmSR7QdzrWg4WhGNtguznL5m3M2mO3p2pMaTWE2v5Gw0ni18D/Gc8m+wAM30BWeoQzZSQJI2MH0n1ryLNXrHjdfYXzm/5yZlA1yltN4BE5e+kivNRw4Ddj8gBTy6CxWrLNLo5tkc0Emeno1HLEgQs6H3j56UXxxj+Gu6DLD+macn1iPvQxD57X7IOv6XT2cA6HL7tffFP41H4e4cpnK3Vrl8h6fSe9U6GDOLLiBY6+UE6NEzsT0iOqAo7dq0HF7OXDoWusxOSFYqIGX0UCstjsPb5YKYS6rdPtbg2lRoC7ltfh3rUX7dt7KrYtEN0knlm2CI16mAn5VsXXN2/sTD+3v8A0UYP971YvZnAXnCBirkawMoa2JYE+mUaDemLwq5/2j4n+QNP4mnKwjo94LnZiFBUFyqKAvVqRqZjXUVx4EWp2deK04me8P2ctqEw4uayMyi3ANu1DQS24gydzNS3gxugXLagZWhRBA29BFRcIQLbh35HUZVVS3JKpMAkmJnXc6TFJSnN6HZulpzmfSI7V2S5TlXMbNBbFtclkoYSXyBR27mDW64d+it/5af+orFXDd5K5mTLCQFVp7RqWj7Vt+Gj2Nr/AC0/9RWnv4NDbyTUortdpbHOAV2lFOoWYaRTGFSxTXFCzUCXKVPuLSrWagCwKKuj2b/ut+RoexRV3yN+635GqWSo8q4T51j9r+elaG3f1uDnOIOH6CGNsTcbygZtW7nKI017is4fwtxcthiNQjDv0ugdZ+TCrPEEqbiG6uhw/Q1ssBNwnpJtMJb7Huu9cqi1jyff/wBOhteml+7Ad5swvrmw9w5iMqA226X6g2qgsNex+feu4WsM3SRNyde+u40Gn1ow3WYXx/h7hlh0FA5BbKcwVwZ13I3NA8KWGbpKzcnXY67roNPrT4mzJYaM7hEkNoxgkadpA/PYV6Z/s98wAM9NzfdTlHToBoJrzTDLo3Sx6iARp2Agep7CvS/AWhUkaBLm3YZNj/3Vb7TLmKnhVxfw19eaA5Xpt9MMQynMRGYxvv8Aq/Gtlgz7O3oPOnpH6UelYW3m/DNKApkeQDLN5ukKRGu2/etrh7ii1azMAM9vcgf80d9Nj+XenQllOpUYq5kBk3wHBzDKwbYZtcszEaa6VlOEN/8AksQM+QFr0t0HQXwYlxA+NaZ8SPxLZ7lv9MBbyEgsuYAZwSerYaelZjAR/vS/CZ4e8QsA684awSI+PvqS50U+xm98U2lWzYCXMqqMQA3QZAZQBJ019ayl831EXbVo22C5HUXrVwaSoIYsl2NiRB0rWeMmBt2SbRP/ABPTCsVOcanWBHqKxNo2gW5WJZGPnsG5iba3D+v7O6ot3PUFZqfQ0lqZa6et4EdVD39j8DRF7zvrPVvQ9/Y/A1QK2N7wfxhiFwuHQMqCyEDQE6lY3VAYbQAin1Osk60d404oL2Iwm3Sy6jUEPcSIg6+U15rdxAW0gDGMokSd5aNNjGaP71J4DfDMpnTm2/UfrLNFLiTF6FhibxbiJNsCVCASSozCN947VbeHnIxeJ5hUNltTlJK+RYgtqdI+c1Rqs44wcvUOodvLsGmrngN5UxWJz3f1bfW7LLdCzrsY207CtPZ9zQ3XY0zXR7/kCf4VE1w/sn7fxNQXeLWB/wAwfIMfyFCXOPWRtmPwX+cVGyptnt3Daw7ICMtpQxETlL2Sy6diFM/Cs1jcSzZuYEzC/dClBEoCeWX7Fio3AG/fc3OGv/iLNm5ZDA27ahuzAG5ZYjQ+UhDPbTWguO2nl2ZsykpkUgHJ0gHI0SASpkAxOsTrW+wV8y7nkWHZQjggk6Qcsxv3O1XWBayirnVWMaasdYE7CPTeqXDOwRwFkGJMjp3ir7hWKKBOWhdiBEIJBAE99N/tVYCy6h/h+1zcSwQvZHKOloQYzJOw771d8Lw+TGosuYU6uzFtbTHWaouGo13FkXhcUm2SQrMraZcoJU7baVo8JhkTF2QggZH3MsTF4STJ9Kj/AJH0n3HwfqrsC+MCPw105iGF23vsRt0xJny6R3MbVhjvW18WsDhbunULtuDPSfUEaRAI79q85N9vU1ScqoWCtssLQXmWjkg52hiLczk2HVmiN4HpMUdxhv8AD3Bn7N7PWPIev0nt60ErddrU6nXeD7OYgJBnfUjbvR3Fi34W5ooWW6v183LOn7sa/Gn6GDcdfQqo/Hrdfpiyow4/5eshJfT49q2HD+abVuVQKLawczMx6NCRlAH1NZfHC9yhmsWbdvonJdzP+jEQotKNdJ10k1pLCMtm0TdYzbSFOUBQUGggAn01qkrp9iS6dxrT6j6f1oHj7uMM2VA4i5mYsq5BkXUAgk/ARtUz3UG7AfFo/jVf4gv2Thj7cqZuBVRxFxsi9L7yNtPfUIPUvPYz3htSLUWsOH1/WCW4GS3BiW1IgzMzM603iTXAwLIqGGiCD6TMVzgiqEOdzZ6jKqLaScqSR7pn37TUPESmbouM4hvMwMbRt86eb4CcVxmmt3l5Fs53L8tC3U5AbKJ7wNa9Q4N/w9j/ACbX/oteYhnGDskouUWbQDZzJGQAHLl0+ten8EH+Gsf5Nr/TWllzeENHl8hUV2KdFKKFhobFOArsU6hYUhsU1hUhqNzQGoguClTbprtA1FdYNF3D0N+635GlSqxAxWG/SWdG/RWPMZP6BNdzodwOwgabVPi0Zrl0Ly2/4foKLnUBySS5TXTUdRiO1cpUj52N9pXYzBXFt3zcw6BSZBVmBcZ9CZuMAdf2e/aqnhJGZ4BHtdZMyZ3GgilSpZbM0FTM/h3EHpOhIJntvA/nXpHgEbdOWUuwNDm6D1Ejua5Sqr5QR5jN4m6n4ZhzHVgpzZWfpViwBC+WZg/LWnYX/iOm3+qek5RA5erdxtLV2lWer/Aar8MG4DdVr78lcmW+nPk+Y8635R26o2in8NzHieKKuEIa9qVLj9MoiJFcpUkOaIZ8rNJxXi166loEqD7eSF3zMCwiYqkx+MdVhsOpHTFxb7SOmULW3tmdIBysK5SqGE24W/5NjaTRjsTiSrtKjUzodtKhuYxSDuDHelSroZo7EF5iRBImF9diBH2Aorw+pDoO/OSI+K0qVN1FRZafjHFwAqCM06iOkmfWibrW+a7WwBbIULAyiQonT40qVLPqvkaPRjTcHrTS3uP2pUqixz0Hw1YdsMpXQKLRJkAyGRo32IVqdxc3A90G4zIxtsEJlUhQvQD5ZIMxvNKlRXJ+QPmXc8kwgcpcykQAM0zJEnar7hl25CraXcAasNIAg7T3NKlVsPclN7lvwjB57+W+gc8tiY90ZdTG1bHgmEtrftKqBRFwR8rg1PyrlKjiJZX3BhyeddjNeMwFwt5CoaLtuGBgyCZncEfLsK81FKlUsXoVwt2WmY57MkRJ06u1sa+aPQag/KiOKsvJca5obWdMuU6R6zSpVToBDMdxLCPay2rt5rvTGa7iGUQBm0c5fXtWg4rjMG+HUWAnM9nmK2yp0HVLFROtKlSObYciKP5VcYcn/d+IygE59Z0heX1EaH3aUqVCG5pbFN4ckW/Z283cSttSFKW4MBiNQV139aj4q7Z+pAphtiDO0zApUqriL2ycX7hrMXhimET2jEBLQCnLAHSANFB0Hvr07gQ/w1j/ACLX+mtKlQxVU/C/2Phu4+Q6KUUqVTHFSpUqwThqJ6VKgEGuGlSpVjH/2Q==\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySt2NUqsKdknDPfBB\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"\r\n\r\nbuilding.jpeg\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySt2NUqsKdknDPfBB--\r\n' }

i want to remove this at starting and end of the data. 
------WebKitFormBoundarySt2NUqsKdknDPfBB\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="profileImage"\r

Comment: from the above object i want only
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEhUTEhIWFRUVFRYWFhUWFxUXFxUVFRUWFhUVFRcYHSggGBolHRUXITEhJSktLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGy0fHyUtMS0tLS0vLS0tLS0tNystLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAIcBdgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAAAAAAAA-----------tKlQxVU/C/2Phu4+Q6KUUqVTHFSpUqwThqJ6VKgEGuGlSpVjH/2Q==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = `Your_Event_Data`
var newText = ''
newText = text.substring(text.indexOf('form-data')+9,text.length)
console.log(newText.indexOf('data'))
newText = newText.substring(newText.indexOf('data'),newText.length)
newText = newText.substring(0,newText.indexOf('WebKitFormBoundary')-7)
```